# How to add name tags to elements

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How to add name tags to elements that are displayed on top of the element?

And move with the element when the model is rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways this could be achieved, one suggestion is to use custom SVG elements which are getting updated using camera event. You can find complete implementation and description of my demo there: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/04/markup3d-sample-for-view-data-api.html